# Define config schema on an installation profile

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a custom installation profile, which has a `profiles/foo/config/install/foo.settings.yml`.

I try to declare a schema in `profiles/foo/config/schema/foo.schema.yml` but it seems that file is not picked up upon installation (it doesn't appear in config-inspector).

Is there a special way to declare the schema for the profile

Comment: For now I have moved the config into a custom module, as the profile was not picked up.